# LINQ Statement not working

Tags: linq

I have a linq method kindly look at it to tell that what's wrong with it..........

```
openQuery = from open in output.result.data
            **where open.activity.Contains(open.activity.Where(act => act.action == Action && act.timestamp.Date >= Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-24))).FirstOrDefault())**
            select open;
```

When the `where` condition commented than the `openQuery` returns the Fields in the REsultView but it gives an enumerationfield error when I de-comment it

Answer (score 0):

If you just execute the query inside the where clause:

```
 open.activity.Where(act => act.action == Action 
                     && act.timestamp.Date >= Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-24)))
```

what do you get?

Comment: it returns an error of:Error  Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'bool' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: Sorry but i can't understand your question

Comment: @MohammadAzeemAhmad The code fragment I gave is not a valid, compilable, program. Therefore you must have run it within other code to get the error.

Comment: @MohammadAzeemAhmad Actually, I'm asking you to. I think your problem is that the where clause you have written is not what you think it is. The way to break down the problem into something that can be fixed is to look at each part. The value you are passing to `Contains` seems to be the clear place to start. Thus that is what I've suggested.

Comment: okay i have break it down now the problem is when i execute the following code than it works quite fine:EmailActivity.AddRange(openQuery.Where(open => open.activity.Contains(open.activity.Where(act => act.action == Action ).FirstOrDefault())));   But as soon as i apply the date check the EmailActivity begins to show null i.e EmailActivity.AddRange(openQuery.Where(open => open.activity.Contains(open.activity.Where(act => act.action == Action && act.timestamp >= Convert.ToDateTime(FromDate)).FirstOrDefault())));

Comment: @MohammadAzeemAhmad Can you add that to the Q (where it can be readable)?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. You do not need to use the Contains() method.

```
openQuery = from open in output.result.data
            where open.activity.action == Action && open.activity.action.timestamp.Date >= Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-24)))
            select open;
```

Comment: It gives the following error: 'System.Collections.Generic.List<PerceptiveMCAPI.Types.campaignEmailStatsAIMResults.EmailActivity.Activity>' does not contain a definition for 'action' and no extension method 'action' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<PerceptiveMCAPI.Types.campaignEmailStatsAIMResults.EmailActivity.Activity>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)